# Get FirstName based on Alias Outlook search in vba

Tags: vba, outlook

I able to do reverse (Get Alias based on Name) by following code: Is it possible to get Name based on Alias ? (I would like to run it in excel spreadsheet)

```
Public Sub GetUsers()

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Dim olNameSpace As Outlook.Namespace
    Set olNameSpace = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Dim olAddrList As Outlook.AddressList
    Set olAddrList = olNameSpace.AddressLists("Global Address List")
Dim oGal As Outlook.AddressEntries
    Set oGal = olAddrList.AddressEntries

Dim myAddrEntry As Outlook.AddressEntry
    Set myAddrEntry = olAddrList.AddressEntries("UserA")
Dim exchUser As Outlook.ExchangeUser
    Set exchUser = myAddrEntry.GetExchangeUser

MsgBox exchUser.Alias

End Sub
```

Based on @Dmitry Streblechenko suggestion. Now problem resolved by following code:

```
Sub GetStaffName()

Dim str As String
    str = Sheets("Form").Range("StaffID").Value
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Dim olNameSpace As Outlook.Namespace
    Set olNameSpace = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Dim olRecipient As Outlook.Recipient
    Set olRecipient = olNameSpace.CreateRecipient(str)
Dim oEU As Outlook.ExchangeUser
Dim oEDL As Outlook.ExchangeDistributionList


olRecipient.Resolve
If olRecipient.Resolved Then
    Select Case olRecipient.AddressEntry.AddressEntryUserType
        Case OlAddressEntryUserType.olExchangeUserAddressEntry
            Set oEU = olRecipient.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser
                If Not (oEU Is Nothing) Then
                    Debug.Print oEU.PrimarySmtpAddress
                End If
            Case OlAddressEntryUserType.olExchangeDistributionListAddressEntry
                Set oEDL = olRecipient.AddressEntry.GetExchangeDistributionList
                    If Not (oEDL Is Nothing) Then
                        Debug.Print oEDL.PrimarySmtpAddress
                    End If
        End Select

    Sheets("Form").Range("StaffName").Value = oEU

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Where do you run the code from? From outlook itself, or a different office application?

Comment: Hi @Bas Verlaat, I would like to run it in excel spreadsheet through vba

Answer (score 1):

you can use this:

```
Public Function GetAliasFromName(sAddressEntry As String) As String

    With New Outlook.Application
        GetAliasFromName = .Session.AddressLists("Global Address List").AddressEntries(sAddressEntry).GetExchangeUser.Alias
    End With

End Function


Public Function GetNameFromAlias(sAlias As String) As String

    Dim oAddressEntry As Outlook.AddressEntry

    On Error Resume Next

    With New Outlook.Application
        For Each oAddressEntry In .Session.AddressLists("Global Address List").AddressEntries
            If oAddressEntry.Class = Outlook.OlObjectClass.olAddressEntry Then
                If oAddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.Alias = sAlias Then
                    GetNameFromAlias = oAddressEntry.Name
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next oAddressEntry
    End With

End Function
```

Comment: HI, I tried to run using Sub Test() MsgBox GetNameFromAlias("115000") End Sub. WHile there is run time error91 at the line If oAddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.Alias = sAlias Then

Comment: I've amended the code to check if the item is an address entry.

Comment: Now i wonder whether there is problem for the Global address List, i able to search by alias by check names button. While the result from above code give sth like $$All_INRHPXMB101V_Users

Comment: Not sure what you mean

Comment: Hi, the first function works perfectly however the second (GetNamefromAlias) returns an incorrect value? Are you aware of an error?

Answer (score 1):

Use `Namespace.CreateRecipient` / `Recipient.Resolve` - it will be able to resolve both a login alias or a last name.

Comment: Hi @Dmitry Streblechenko, is there any documentation and example of this method?

Comment: There is not much to do document - you just pass a string and get back a Recipient object: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866418.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: This is the correct answer  Looping through the GAL is a waste of time and resources.  It'd be nice if `AddressEntries` had an `Items` property supporting a `Restrict()` method with which to query aliases.  But since such features aren't available, creating a recipient resolver is the next best thing.  In PowerShell, I do `$recipient = $namespace.CreateRecipient($user); if ($recipient.Resolve()) { return $recipient.Name }`.  You solved a problem that's been nagging me for the past several hours Dmitry.  Thank you!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipient.resolve

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Function GetNameFromAlias2(sAlias As String) As String

    Dim oAddressEntry As Outlook.AddressEntry

    On Error Resume Next

    With New Outlook.Application
     For Each oAddressEntry In .Session.AddressLists("Global Address List").AddressEntries
      If oAddressEntry.Class = Outlook.OlObjectClass.olAddressEntry Then
       If oAddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.Alias = sAlias Then
        GetNameFromAlias2 = oAddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.Alias
        Exit For
       End If
      End If
     Next oAddressEntry
    End With

End Function
```

@Bas Verlaat, the first function works smoothly, but the second is exactly what I need. However, it's not giving the correct result, I get: 01_New Requests
on every cell.

Comment: Never ever loop through all entries in a GAL container - some of them can contain tens of thousands of entries. Use Namespace.CreateRecipient / Recipient.Resolve.