# VBA: how can I get a list of the SMTP email addresses for the current outlook user?

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I know how to get the primary email address of the current user, but how can I get a full list of all their SMTP email addresses?

I'm looking for the information you can get when you right-click on a recipient in an email and go to "open outlook properties" and go to the "E-mail Addresses" tab

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

and for those of you who've never used getProperty, the code looks like this -

```
Const PR_EMS_AB_PROXY_ADDRESSES  As String = _
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x800F101F"

Dim NS As Outlook.NameSpace
Set NS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

addresses = _
NS.CurrentUser.AddressEntry.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(PR_EMS_AB_PROXY_ADDRESSES)
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the `PR_EMS_AB_PROXY_ADDRESSES` MAPI property (DASL name `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x800F101F`) using `Namespace.CurrentUser.AddressEntry.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty`.

Each address will be prefixed with the address type (e.g. "EX:" or "smtp:"). The default SMTP address will be prefixed with "SMTP:" (all capitals).

You can see the property in [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author) - click IMAPISession button, then QueryIdentity